# Converting media content into string in Java

Tags: java, android, base64, oracle-maf

I'm using `Oracle-MAF` for mobile app development (Android and IOS). Having a requirement to capture media (image, audio and video) in the application and want to store into `Oracle DB` usually CLOB column.

So for I converted the captured media into `base64` string (using `commons-codec-1.10.jar`) and passing through Rest webservice (`Accept JSON/XML`) to store into DB.

For image and audio length of the base64 string is fine, but for video it is consuming around `6.4 million` of characters even for `2 sec video` (`2MB Rear camera`) and this cause slow down the application and resulting **Java heap space error**.

Is there any other way to convert the media content into String using Java which gives feasible solution?

Comment: You could use compression to get better performance.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, Is it fine after converting I can able to send it as JSON?

Comment: And one more ques, As suggested I was looking on http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/compress-1565076.html this link. In the base64 string already I'm having number in it (Sample: iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASwAAACWCAYAAABkW7XSAAAOQUlEQVR4Xu2dv64sRxGHbfEAxhkBkhdBiGSQyEBinSP58if3IpFzkcgIOPcF4DpGgnVGgmyLB2AJyJBsQiKPxQvYD4BM), then how it could decompressed it correctly. If you have any other link for compression and decompression? If so please share...

Answer (score 0):

If it's really necessary to save the videos in CLOB/BLOB column of a table in DB then first save the content in a file and then have an asynchronous scheduler to save it in the DB. The best would be to have this scheduler running in another Java VM not to interfere with the app server running your server side.

If you can save all binary content as binary in a file and a path in the DB. File systems are the best solution for serving binary data anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, File system does't suites my requirement. Since later the same media content have to be accessed in another device. I will check with your first approach and get back to you. One question, Is it possible to have scheduler in android/ios device?

Comment: The file should be saved on the server next to the Oracle DB. Configure an Apache or Nginx server to serve those binary files and they'll be available to all devices.